# Do I have to fill new DS-160 form or I can use the previous one?

Tags: usa

I hope you'll help me on this matter!

Well, I have filled up 2 new different DS-160 form for X university and Y university. First, I filled one DS form for X, however, I wanted to change the university. So I thought to retrieve the DS form of X to change but I didn't do that. Simply, I started a new DS form for Y and submitted it. After that, I updated the new confirmation number of Y in the CGI. Well, I haven't paid SEVIS fee yet.

But the main problem is that I want to go again with X in the interview. In this case, do I have to fill up new DS form for X or I can use the previous DS form of X?

I think if I filled new DS for X, I'll fill twice for X. Does that matter? So what if I use the previous DS form of X and update that confirmation number in the CGI? As I have mentioned, I haven't retrieved or edited the DS form of X so I think I can use that.

I'll be lookin forward to your advice! Thank you!